# Use me.com "find my iPhone" programmatically

Tags: iphone, gps

Greetings!

My wife, my 9 year old, and myself all have iPhones with me.com subscriptions. One of the "killer features" (at least for me) in the 3.0 firmware was the "find my iPhone" functionality. I would like to build some sort of tool that would poll the "find my iPhone" service every once in a while, and I could build some sort of database of all the places our 3 iPhones have been throughout the day.  Does anyone have any ideas as to how such a service could be built easily?

Thanks!

Comment: Your 9 year old has an iPhone?!?! Kids these days...

Comment: Whatever happened to a tin can and a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check [findmyiphone](http://github.com/mattb/findmyiphone/) - that's a ruby script, or similar projects in [php](http://github.com/tylerhall/sosumi/) or [java](http://github.com/spullara/findmyiphone/)

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that there is a public API for reading the location of any iPhone at any time as this would be a stalkers' dream.

If you have the me.com login credentials for all of the phones in your family, you could likely scrape the info off of a WebKit/IE control when it is showing the Find My iPhone page.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider signing up for Google Latitude instead.  That might provide a lot of the location functionality you're looking for without having to write anything yourself.  [www.google.com/latitude](http://www.google.com/latitude)

Comment: Google Latitude kind of sucks on the iPhone, though, as Apple does not allow them to update the location in the background.  That means you have to go to the Google Latitude website to update your location.

(GL works much better on Android; my location is always up to date, and it uses very little battery to do so.)

Comment: If only Google offered a Latitude submit API, then a jailbreak dev could write a background daemon that updated the position whenever the phone wakes to check mail ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably figuring out how to scrape the mobileMe site, since it's really the only thing allowed to ask the phone where it is.  You'd have to build an app that simulated a login and then parsed the results from the mobileMe site.

Answer (score 0):

ATT has a family map feature.  It costs $10 month to track up to 2 phones and I think $15 to track up to 5.  I've tried it at it works pretty well.  I thought it was a bit creepy too at first but you can only follow phone numbers tied to your account.  Also once a number is being followed a text is sent to that number informing them and also a text is sent to the primary number on the account.   att.com/familymap